# Get Application's Permission for installed applications in iOS device

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

How to get App's Permission for each app installed in iOS device? How to do it programmatically on iOS?

Comment: I want to display the installed applications permissions such as Camera, Maps, User Location, etc. How to get these permissions for each application installed in device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get the information and permissions of other apps.
Each app runs in a sand-boxed environment.

You can't access Other third-party apps or System Apps features or permissions via your app. There is no public API available to do so.